# Hard limit for number requests to Google Fusion Tables? Pricing plans?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Is there a hard limit for the number of requests we can make to Fusion Tables per day? If so, how many and does anyone know about the pricing plans (if any) beyond that limit?

Answer (score 5):

The limits are 25000 requests per day with read methods counting as one request and write requests counting as five:

https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/release_notes

You can also see the quotas for all your Google APIs at the Google API console under the "Quotas" tab:

https://code.google.com/apis/console

There are also forms there to request more quota.